# Could not bundle install because of 'eventmachine 1.0.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, eventmachine

$ bundle install

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

$ gem list

```
eventmachine (1.0.3 x86-mingw32)
```

$ gem build eventmachine -v 1.0.3

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Too many gem names (eventmachine, 1.0.3); please specify only one
```

Comment: Check you `Gemfile` if there are more than once `gem eventmachine` define.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to edit Gemfile.lock and change eventmachive version from 1.0.3 to 1.0.4.
This works for me.

Comment: @Andrey but how we can handle in production there we should not edit the gemlock file

Comment: @yaswantsingh : you can remove `Gemfile.lock` and then run `bundle install` this works fine for me

Comment: Thank you, this worked even in 2021 when I was trying to fix someone's very old app.

Answer (score 8):

- bundle update
- bundle install Hope this will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with `eventmachine -v '1.0.4'` and i resolved it like this.

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.4'  -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```